# EditInputType for GuidedAction doesn't work in Android TV application

Tags: android, android-tv

The edit input still show clear text even after I setup the EditInputType like this in my Android TV application:

```
actions.add(new GuidedAction.Builder()
                .id(id)
                .title(title)
                .editInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD)
                .editable(id == 2)
                .description(desc)
                .build());
```

Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following code solves the problem.

```
    actions.add(
        new GuidedAction.Builder(this.getActivity())
            .id(id)
            .title(title)
            .description(desc)
            .editDescription(editDescription)
            .descriptionEditInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
            .descriptionEditable(true)
            .build());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe you can help me. I'd like to give the chance to user to show and hide the password (the typical checkbox you know), do you know how to "enable/disable" show and hide in password?